# How to exctract filtered items from SharePoint List to Excel

Tags: list, javascript, excel, excel-services

I'm using Javascript and AngularJS to get all data from a SharePoint list in JSON and displayed it into a table. User can sort it, filtered it and etc. There is a really nice paggination.
Everything is working perfectly.
There was a problem with displaying it because in my List are available Multilines Column and in JSON and in a view users are seeing all HTML tags. But AngularJS is so cool and thanks of filters all data is now representing beautiful (bold text, links, br and etc).
Unfortunately I have another issue. I'm trying to add some feature that sorted and filtered data can be extracted to EXCEL. And it must work in IE. That's why I'm using

> ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")

In this way I can extract a JSON to a Excel. But there are visible all HTML tags.
I can remove them before sending the data to Excel but text is not formatted and the links are not working.

Is there any solution for such kind of issue? Maybe there is some Excel-services or something?

P.S. I have some idea but maybe it's not a good one. I can exctract all the data to some new List in SharePoint. Before extraction I 'll remove all records from it. So I will have a SharePoint List with data which I need and I can export the List to EXCEL. I'm not sure if extraction will take care about text formatting and how much time it will require. For sure there will be a problem when 2 users are trying to extract filtered List.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenXML with SharePoint to generate Excel worksheets. Have a look at following:

[Creating and Publishing Excel 2010 Documents with Custom SharePoint 2010 Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg317441(v=office.14).aspx)

[OpenXML Excel Generation - CodePlex](https://openxmlexcel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DemoOpenXMLExcel/DemoOpenXMLExcel/Program.cs)

Comment: I forgot to wrote that I don't have access to server. So I can manipulate everything only with JavaScript.